# Is the following code a valid OpenMP parallel program?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm studying for an exam at the moment and one of the practice questions is to write a piece of code which implements the parallel sum of all element of an array on an SMP computer. I've written a few OpenMP programs before which were much large but didn't take advantage really of the clauses and directives and I came across the reduction clause so I was wondering if the following piece is a parallel program because I'm wondering how relatively simplistic could one reduce the program to but still retain parallelisation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>


int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    double * X;
    X = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ X[i] = 2.0; }

    int i = 0;
    double sum = 0.0;

    omp_set_num_threads(atoi(argv[2]));

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i), shared(X) reduction(+: sum)
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        sum += X[i];
    }

    printf("Sum is : %0.2f\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I came across the reduction clause so I was wondering if the
> following piece is a parallel program

From the OpenMP standard on the `#pragma omp parallel` :

> When a thread encounters a **parallel construct**, **a team of threads is
> created to execute the parallel region.** The thread that encountered
> the parallel construct becomes the master thread of the new team, with
> a thread number of zero for the duration of the new parallel region.
> All threads in the new team, including the master thread, execute the
> region. Once the team is created, the number of threads in the team
> remains constant for the duration of that parallel region.

So yes, it is a parallel program as long as the number of threads that you have explicitly set it on the method:

```
omp_set_num_threads(atoi(argv[2]));
```

is greater than 1.

In:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i), shared(X) reduction(+: sum)
```

The private `i` can be omitted, because since it is used as the `index` on the parallel loop, OpenMP will make it private.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just run it and test. You can run something like this on your laptop/desktop as well.
Yes, the reduction operation in this code is parallel (sum computation).
However, setting elements of array `X` to `2.0` is sequential. You would want a `#pragma omp parallel for` over `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ X[i] = 2.0; }` in order to make the program truly parallel. Otherwise, Amdahl's law will apply.